# Set object in the json response returned intermittently

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I have one peculiar problem where in set object in json response does not appear always for the same request.

The below is the json response class

```
public class EmployeeEntity implements Serializable {

    
    /** The id. */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long  employeeEntityId;

    /** The name. */
    @Column(name = "name", length = 45, unique=true)
    private String employeeName;

    /** The description. */
    @Column(name = "instruction", columnDefinition = "mediumtext")
    private String description;

    /** The employee permissions. */
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinTable(name = "employee_has_permissions", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_permissions_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private Set<EmployeePermissionEntity> employeePermissions;
    
    //setters and getters
    }
```

In local environment this works perfectly fine. But in dev environment for the same request which has employee permissions, intermittently employee permission is not being shown in the response. I am not able to figure out what is going wrong here. Could you please help me out here.

**EDIT :** I face this issue with zuul gateway. Upon further analysis I could see that whenever tags are missing call has not come to the application. Does this mean gateway is caching the response partially? If so how to prevent that or make it cache full response.

This is the response construct code.

```
        HttpServletResponse response; //received as method parameter
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.info("Construct resposne : ");
        }
    
        final EmpResponseModel empResponse = new EmpResponseModel(firstName,
                lastName, token, id, employeeEntity.employeePermissions());
        final ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel(OK, "Operation completeted successfully.", null,
                new ResponseModel<EmpResponseModel>(empResponse));
        try (OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
            //mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
            mapper.writeValue(out, responseModel);
            out.flush();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.info("Exception while writing response : " + exception);
            }
        }
```

Comment: When I recall properly, this may be due the FetchType.LAZY - my memory is rather vague, but have you tried to set it to eager?

Comment: As @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) is there it takes care of that. It works fine in local environment. I have tried with 20-25 consecutive requests.